# reversing a queue in a non-conventional way

Tags: algorithm, recursion, queue

Suppose I have a queue filled with some type of elements, and they are filled in such a way that if any two elements are the assessed as the same by a designated comparer, they will be adjacent to each other.

Now I want to reverse the queue in the following way: If all elements in the queue are unique, then reverse it as the normal definition of reverse.

If there are some elements that are the same (and they will be adjacent to each other given how they are filled in), reverse the queue but keep the relative position of the non-unique elements intact.

A diagram might be easier to understand what the problem is.

If a queue is as the following:

```
[11 22 33 44 55]
```

and my comparer compares two integers by looking at their first digit, then the reverse of the queue above would be:

```
[55 44 33 22 11]
```

However, if my input queue is:

```
[11 22 23 44 55]
```

the reverse should be:

```
[55 44 22 23 11]
```

given the comparer.

I am trying to do this in a recursive way with only one stack as an additional auxiliary storage. However, I am having difficulty figuring out a correct and effective way. Could you please help? Thank you very much!

PS: The reason I am using a stack as extra storage is because reversing a queue in the conventional way is done most easily with a stack (dequeue and push all into stack, then pop and enqueue back into the queue).

Comment: 22 and 23 are not different elements?

Comment: @JavaNewb No they are not different, since the comparer only looks at the first digit in this example.

Comment: @joeframbach It is not a typo. The definition of "being the same" is given by a particular comparer, it is not necessarily the conventional way of defining the same.

Comment: @joeframbach No worries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1)**

First reverse the whole Queue (without consideration of equality of 21,22 etc), then reverse each individual block (i.e. 21,22 etc) using a stack. This can be done iteratively.

This is similar to the reverse words in a sentence problem (famous interview question).

(See worked out example and pseudo code below)

**Approach 2)**

If you want to absolutely do recursion, then I would suggest you use a Queue as your auxiliary storage, not a stack.

You enque a block into the auxiliary queue, recursively reverse the rest of the list, and then enqueu the elements back into the main queue.

The code will be something like this (handwavy pseudo)

```
StrangeReverse(Queue <T> q) {
    Queue<T> aux;
    // this removes first block from q, and places them in aux
    while (elem_of_first_block(q)) {
        aux.Enque(elem);
    }
    // Recursively reverse the rest of the q.
    StrangeReverse(q);

    // place the first block back in q, at the end.
    // in the order they appeared originally.
    while (aux.HasElements()) {
        q.Enque(aux.Deque());
    }
}
```

The recursive version can be converted to iterative, by having a stack of queues! You create a queue out of each block, and stack them up. Then pop the stack, the use the queues.

**A worked out example of Approach 1**

`[11, 12, 21, 22, 43, 44]`

Reverse this (either using the stack or by a recursive method)

`[44, 43, 22, 21, 12, 11]`

Now reverse each block:

`push 44, the 43.`

`Stack = [44, 43]. Queue = [22, 21, 12, 11]`

Now Enque by popping from the stack

`Stack = [], Queue = [22, 21, 12, 11, 43, 44]`

`push 22, 21`

`Stack = [22, 21], Queue = [12, 11, 43, 44]`

Enque by popping the stack.

`Stack = [], Queue = [12, 11, 43, 44, 21, 22]`

Finally we get

`[43, 44, 21, 22, 11, 12]`

Note: to determine a block you might need a peek method on the Queue.

**Pseudo code of Approach 1**

```
void StrangeReverse(Queue<T> q) {
    Stack<T> s;
    int count = q.Count();
    if (count < 2) return;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        T elem = q.Deque();
        s.Push(elem);
    }    
    while (s.HasElements()) {
        T elem = s.Pop();
        q.Enque(elem);
    }
    // Now the queue has been reversed,
    // in the normal fashion.
    ReverseBlocks(q);
}

void ReverseBlocks(Queue<T> q) {
    int reversed = 0;
    int count = q.Count();
    while (reversed < count) {
        reversed += ReverseSingleBlock(q);
    }
}

int ReverseSingleBlock(Queue <T> q) {
    Stack <T> s;
    T prevElem = q.Deque();
    s.Push(prevElem);
    T curElem = q.Peek();
    while(curElem == prevElem) {
        s.Push(curElem);
        q.Deque();
        prevElem = curElem;
        curElem = q.Peek();
    }
    int count = 0;
    while(s.HasElements()) {
        T elem = s.Pop();
        q.Enque(elem);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @Enzo: This answer is not helpful? Not even worth commenting? :-)

Comment: Sorry! I was dealing with other issues earlier... This is very helpful and exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! Given approach 1 I think doing this iteratively would be better! Thank you again!

Comment: @Enzo: No worries. Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

still assuming:
enque -> [11,21,22,23,30] -> deque/peek
should be better now:

```
first = queue.peek();
start = true;
while (queue.peek() != first || start) {
  start = false;
  el = queue.deque();
  if (el.compare(queue.peek())) {
    stack.push(el);
    while (el.compare(queue.peek())) {
      el1 = queue.dequeue();
      if (first.compare(el1)) {
        first = el1;
      }
      stack.push(el1);
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      queue.enque(stack.pop());       
    }
  } else {
    queue.enque(el);
  }
}
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
  stack.push(queue.deque());
}
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
  queue.enque(stack.pop());
}
```

so first i'm rotating the queue, changing the order of the "equivalent" elements
and finally i'm doing an ordinary queue reverse

Comment: this would only work if the number of non-unique items are two I think.
For example, it would not work on this:
[11 21 22 23 33 44]

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ReverseQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, limit=5):
        self.rear = None
        self.front = None
        self.que = []
        self.size = 0
        self.limit = limit

   def enQueue(self, item):
        if self.size >= self.limit:
            print "Queue Overflow"
            return
        else:
            self.que.append(item)

        # two case
        # 1. if front is None then the queue is empty.
        #    so if item is added both front
        #    end point to the same position i.e 0
        # 2. if front is not None then item is added to the end of the
        #    list(append does that). we then increase the size of rear

        # note: rear is 0 indexed but size is not
        # that's why there's a diff of 1 always b/w these rear and size
        if self.front is None:
            self.rear = self.front = 0
            self.size = 1
        else:
            self.rear = self.size
            self.size += 1

        return

    def deQueue(self):
          if self.size <= 0:
              print "Queue Underflow"
              return
          else:
              temp = self.que.pop(0)

          # change the size
          self.size -= 1

          # if list is empty set both front and rear = None
          # This is in sync with the queue method
          #  where we check if front = none when adding item
          # change front and rear
          if self.size is 0:
             # if only one element
             self.rear = self.front = None
          else:
             # more then one element
             self.rear -= 1

          return temp

      def isEmpty(self):
          return self.size <= 0

      def reverse(self):
          if not self.isEmpty():
              temp = self.deQueue()
              self.reverse()
              self.enQueue(temp)
```

myQueue = ReverseQueue()

myQueue.enQueue("First")

myQueue.enQueue("Second")

myQueue.enQueue("Third")

myQueue.enQueue("Fourth")

myQueue.enQueue("Fifth")

print myQueue.que

myQueue.reverse()

print myQueue.que

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet to reverse a C++ STL queue using recursion.

```
void reverseQueue(queue<int>& q){
    while(q.size() != 0){
        q.pop();

        reverseQueue(q);

        q.push(value);
        break;
    }
}
```